# Passing the values from dynamically created textboxes to an array using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I wanted to add textboxes dynamically and then pass the values written in these textboxes to
an array. here is my code.

```
    function add(type)
 {
    a=new Array();
    for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
           var element = document.createElement("input");
           element.setAttribute("type", type);
           element.setAttribute("value", type);
           element.setAttribute("name", type);
           element.setAttribute("id", 'n'+c);
           var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
           a[i]=document.getElementById('n'+c);
           foo.appendChild(element);

        }
  }
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <FORM>

    <SELECT name="element">
    <OPTION value="button">Button</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
     <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
     <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
```

thanks....

Comment: Err, you are doing a[i] while you are using the counter c, shouldn't it be a[c]? (you 'should' also use [] instead of new Array())

Comment: sorry that a[i] was a typing error! Still not working

Comment: @NatashaGupta : does the below answer helps you?

Comment: NO. still not working!:(

Comment: @NatashaGupta : check out the updated answer with working example http://jsbin.com/EPOtuno/1/edit

Comment: @NatashaGupta : does this answers your question mam?

Comment: thank u so much guys! Amith and Aditya both ur answers are working! u ppl rock! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here try this!!!

```
var a= [];
function add(type) {
for(c=0;c<3;c++){
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("value", type);
element.setAttribute("name", type);
element.setAttribute("id", 'n'+c);
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
foo.appendChild(element);
a[c]=document.getElementById('n'+c).value;
}
}
function show(){
for(c=0;c<3;c++){
alert(a[c]);
}
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<SELECT name="element">
<OPTION value="text">Text</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/><br>
<INPUT type=button  name="b1" value="Show" onclick="show()"/><br>
<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: @NatashaGupta : may i know what was wrong with the answer i posted long back?

Comment: nothing wrong....working flawlessly...its just that i dont have enuf reputations to vote and i had the option of selecting only 1 accepted answer!!

Answer (score 2):

try this

HTML

```
<form>
    <select name="element">
        <option value="button">Button</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
    <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
</form>
```

JS

```
function add(type)
 {
    a=new Array();
    for(c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
           var element = document.createElement("input");
           element.setAttribute("type", "text");
           element.setAttribute("value", type);
           element.setAttribute("name", "mytextbox");
           element.setAttribute("id", 'n'+c);
           var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
           foo.appendChild(element);
           a[c]=document.getElementById('n'+c).value;

        }
  }
```

Working `JSBin` example

http://jsbin.com/EPOtuno/1/edit

Comment: @Nathasha : checkout the updated answer with working example http://jsbin.com/EPOtuno/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem is that the element isn't part of the document until you call `foo.appendChild(element);` so doing `document.getElementById('n'+c);` isn't returning anything. However, that's totally unnecessary anyway. If it *were* part of the document, `document.getElementById('n'+c);` is just going to return exactly what you already have referenced by `element`, so you should be able to just do:

```
a[c] = element;
```